# A mathematical number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

Can you deduce the next three terms and long term behaviour?

> $$0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 22, 29, 45, 100, \dots$$

This sequence is not in the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) (OEIS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> The sums of the digits of each to consecutive numbers are multiplied and then to the product 1 is added 
>  
>  For example: 
>  0 x 1 + 1 = 1
>  1 x 1 + 1 = 2
>  ...
>  3 x 7 + 1 = 22
>  7 x 4 + 1 = 29  (2 + 2 = 4)
>  therefore:
>  9 x 1 + 1  = 10
>  1 x 1 + 1 = 2
>  1 x 2 + 1 = 3
>
>  so, the next 3 numbers are 10, 2, 3

Comment: Yes, good job, well done :-)